# Text overflow in div tag

Tags: css, html

I type long string in `div`or `span` tag whenever i maximise the window (any browser) , it perfectly matches the div tag but when i minimise it or compress the browser width then text coming out of div area . I just want to know how to set long text in a div area either stretched or compressed . I tried `ellipsis` , `white-space:nowrap` .. nothing result i found .
Is there any other solution for it ?

screen ex: When i compressed the browser width.
[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have currently, so that we can fully understand what you mean. http://jsfiddle.net may be handy.

Comment: wait a minute will give screens for it

Comment: code would be better than screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want something like this:

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/nrVJf/)

**CSS:**

```
div {
    // Div Styles Without Fixed Width and Height
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}​
```

If you are using fixed height for `<div>` then you must define either a css property `overflow:auto` (for scrollbar to appear while content varies), or `overflow:hidden;` (to hide the text varies)

[**SEE EXAMPLE (overflow:auto)**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/nrVJf/7/)

[**SEE EXAMPLE (overflow:hidden)**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/nrVJf/8/)

Comment: I dont want hide nor i want to stretch my div